# Java: changing the order of lines with while-loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am new to programming and I would like to ask what should I do so that the final value of k  will appear before the values of a, when I try to put it inside the loop it repeats the statement and when I put it before the loop, its value is 0.

```
    System.out.printf("Input an integer: ");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    int k = 0;
    
    System.out.print(a);
    while(a > 1)
    {
        if(a % 2 == 0)
            a = a / 2;
        else
            a = 3 * a + 1;
        System.out.printf(", " + a);
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nk = " + k);


    Output:
    Input an integer: 10
    10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
    k = 6
```

Comment: You need to _collect_ the values of `a` into a list or array (if you can calculate the number of expected values at the start - a list is easier though) and print the list/array after printing `k`. Think about it like this: you're writing the values of a onto a separate piece of paper and once you're done and wrote `k` onto the solution sheet you take that separate piece of paper and copy the numbers on it to your sheet as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```java
    System.out.printf("Input an integer: ");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    int k = 0;
    String str_a = "";
    
    System.out.print(a);
    while(a > 1)
    {
        if(a % 2 == 0)
            a = a / 2;
        else
            a = 3 * a + 1;
        str_a += ", " + String.valueOf(a);
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println("k = " + k);
    System.out.println("a = " + str_a);
```